# How can I make same day message in one section?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

```
import UIKit

class MessageDetailViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView!
    
    struct data{
        let time: String
        let message: String
        let date: String
        let type: String
    }
    
    struct section {
        let date: String
        var array = [data]()
    }
    
    let sectionArray = [
        section(date: "yesterday", array: [
            data(time: "3:30 PM", message: "I am looking for your service, can you please give more information on that.", date: "yesterday", type: "sender"),
            data(time: "3:40 PM", message: "Sure i am here to help you", date: "yesterday", type: "receiver")
            ]),
        section(date: "today", array: [data(time: "4:40 PM", message: "Ok, I wil contact you on your phone for that.", date: "today", type: "sender")])
    ]
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        self.tableview.register(UINib(nibName: "SenderCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "SenderCell")
        self.tableview.register(UINib(nibName: "ReceiverCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "ReceiverCell")
        self.tableview.register(UINib(nibName: "customHeaderViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "customHeaderViewCell")
    }
}
```

```
extension MessageDetailViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{
    
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return sectionArray.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return sectionArray.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
         if sectionArray[indexPath.section].array[indexPath.row].type == "sender"
        {
            let cell = tableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SenderCell", for: indexPath) as! SenderCell
            cell.setData(reciverTime: sectionArray[indexPath.section].array[indexPath.row].time, reciverMsg: sectionArray[indexPath.section].array[indexPath.row].message)
            return cell
        }
        else
        {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ReceiverCell", for: indexPath) as! ReceiverCell
            cell.setData(reciverTime: sectionArray[indexPath.section].array[indexPath.row].time, reciverMsg: sectionArray[indexPath.section].array[indexPath.row].message)
            return cell
        }
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 100
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    
        let headerView = UIView()
        let headerCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customHeaderViewCell") as! customHeaderViewCell
        if sectionArray[section].date == "yesterday"{
            headerCell.labelHeader.text = "yesterday"
        }
        else{
            headerCell.labelHeader.text = "today"
        }
        headerView.addSubview(headerCell)
        return headerView
    }
}
```

This is my message detail code.

I want to achieve these[image: 1]

But through these array I achieved these[image: 2]

what changes should I do in my code so that I can get same day message in one section

this ---

sectionArray.append(section(date: "yesterday", array: [data(time: "3:40 PM", message: "SURE i am here to help you", date: "yesterday", type: "receiver")]))

Making a new section I don't want to make new section when sure I am here o help you array comes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I've seen your code, you're using `String` to indicate the day of the message which is bad practice. Instead, you should use `Date`, which will help you group the messages by date:

```
let sectionArray = messages.reduce(into: [section]()) { result, element in
    if let section = result.firstIndex(where: {Calendar.current.isDate($0.date, inSameDayAs: element.date)}) {
        result[section].append(element)//append message to section
    }else {
        //create new section
    }
}
```

If you really need to use `String`, use this:

```
let sectionArray = messages.reduce(into: [section]()) { result, element in
    if let section = result.firstIndex(where: {$0.date == element.date}) {
        result[section].append(element)//append message to section
    }else {
        //create new section
    }
}
```

Comment: i want to use string for day just for now i want to learn by string how can i make sections can you please help me put

Comment: i dont want to do thsese i want to make changes in array only

Comment: This is creating a new array, nothing is changing

Comment: can you show me how can i make section throgh array so when second array comes it goes to first section

Comment: i updated my array can you show me how can i access these array into my cell for row at ??

Comment: cell for row at comes index outof range

Comment: you need to combine those 2 "yesterday" into one. Add the code in my answer to your `viewDidLoad` to combine them & get an array of `section` not `[section]`

Comment: still it is out of index updated answer

Comment: In `numberOfRowsInSection`, you should return this `return sectionArray[section].array.count`

Comment: thank you so much dear i gave almost my half day in thses thank you so much